# Knime List Files node regex filter broken on \+ (plus character)

Tags: regex, knime

In the List Files node applying regular expression filter

```
.*\+.*
```

or

```
.*[+].*
```

was working perfectly in Knime 3.3.2 (Windows 7, 64 bit). I have right now upgraded to 3.4.2, and it creates empty table on the same directory with files having '+' sign in file name.

I have a workaround: I read the entire directory without any filter, and if I apply Rule-based Row Filter node with

```
$Column_name$ MATCHES .*\+.*
```

or

```
$Column_name$ MATCHES .*[+].*
```

it works, so it seems a List Files node specific issue.

Does anybody has any idea why regex filter with '+' sign broken in List Files node?

Comment: Sorry, Knime 3.2.1 was the version I have upgraded from, not 3.3.2.

Comment: I guess [this](https://www.knime.com/changelog-v34) causes the trouble in your case: "AP-7483: List Files RegEx checks encoded URL instead of file path"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try your filtering with:

```
.*?%2[bB].*
```

(I have added the `?` for non-greedy reading after the first `.*`) `%2B` is the `+` sign URL encoded.

This behaviour was caused by the

> AP-7483: List Files RegEx checks encoded URL instead of file path

[change in KNIME 3.4](https://www.knime.com/changelog-v34).